# Genero PDF pero al generar otro se sobreescribe el primer PDF [Java Swing y libreria iText 5.11]

Tags: java, java-swing, itext

estoy creando una aplicación en java swing en la cual tiene que generar un PDF con codigos de barra, el sistema funciona de la siguiente manera: es una interfaz donde utiliza un spinner, el jspinner trae la cantidad de codigos de barra que se dibujarán en el PDF y despues un jcombobox que escogera el codigo de barras que esta en la base de datos.

Hasta aqui todo bien al presionar el boton me crea el PDF correctamente. Además de eso, se genera con un nombre en el especial, donde el nombre es codigo de barras + la hora y la
fecha en que se genero.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

el problema esta cuando quiero generar otro PDF con otra cantidad en el Spinner y de otro modelo del jcombobox, cuando lo hago si se crea, pero se sobreescribe el ultimo PDF que genere, es decir si la primera vez tenia 6 en el jspinner y se genera, cuando lo vuelvo hacer con 3 abro ese mismo archivo y me aparecen 3 por lo cual se esta sobreescribiendo el archivo, lo raro es que no sobreescribe el formato de salida, es decir si cree un archivo PDF el 22/06/2021 a las 9:53  y genero otro PDF 20 min despues no me aparece un nuevo archivo llamado 22/06/2021 a las 10:13 si no que se sobreescribe el primero y eso es lo que no entiendo :(

Al menos que cierre la aplicacion y vuelva a correrla me genera otro nuevo PDF ya con la hora y fecha de ese momento pero la funcionalidad no debe ser asi.

Adjunto mi codigo que estoy trabajando, estoy usando MVC con java

Este es mi clase codigo de barras

```
package Models;

public class codigosBarras {
    
    private String modelo;
    private String codigo;
    
    public codigosBarras(){
    }

    public codigosBarras(String modelo, String codigo) {
        this.modelo = modelo;
        this.codigo = codigo;
    }

    public String getModelo() {
        return modelo;
    }

    public void setModelo(String modelo) {
        this.modelo = modelo;
    }

    public String getCodigo() {
        return codigo;
    }

    public void setCodigo(String codigo) {
        this.codigo = codigo;
    }    
}
```

Esta es mi clase consultas_codigos.java que se conecta con la base de datos y genera el PDF con los codigos de barras. estoy mostrando unicamente el metodo que utilizo para generar el PDF

```
        public void generarCodigosEnPDF(String codigo, int cantidad){        
        int codigo_aleatorio = 0;
        String query = "SELECT codigo_barras FROM inventario_general WHERE modelo = '"+codigo+"';";
        System.out.println(query);
        String resultado_codigo = "";
        
        try (Connection conn = getConnection();
            Statement st = conn.createStatement();
            ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery(query))
        {
            if (rs.next()) {
                resultado_codigo = rs.getString("codigo_barras");
            }
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            System.out.println("Error 351: " + ex + " No se pudo pana");
        }
        
        try {
            int i = 1;
            Document doc = new Document(); //paso 1: creamos el documento

            pdf = PdfWriter.getInstance(doc, new FileOutputStream("codigo_barras_"+fecha+".pdf")); //paso 2: instanciamos el doc y donde se creara
            doc.open(); //paso 3: abrimos el documento
            Barcode128 code128 = new Barcode128();
            
            while (i <= cantidad) {                
                codigo_aleatorio = (r.nextInt(10000)+1);
                code128.setCode(resultado_codigo);
                code128.setCodeType(Barcode128.CODE128);
                

                Image img = code128.createImageWithBarcode(pdf.getDirectContent(), BaseColor.BLACK, BaseColor.BLACK);
                img.scalePercent(220);
                img.setAlignment(Element.ALIGN_CENTER);
                
                Paragraph titulo = new Paragraph("Codigo de Fabricante: " + codigo_aleatorio, new com.itextpdf.text.Font(com.itextpdf.text.Font.FontFamily.COURIER, 12));
                titulo.setAlignment(Element.ALIGN_CENTER);
                float scaler = ((doc.getPageSize().getWidth() - doc.leftMargin() - doc.rightMargin() - 0 / img.getWidth()) * 60);
                
                
                doc.add(titulo); //añadimos el doc
                doc.add(img);
                doc.add(new Paragraph(" "));
            i++; //iterador
            
            }
            doc.close(); //cerramos el 
            
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Codigos de Barra Generados Correctamente!");           
            
        } catch (DocumentException | HeadlessException | IOException ex) {
            System.out.println("Error 6164:" + ex);
        }      
    }
```

Esta es mi clase controlador_codigo.java que es el controlador, este se comunica con la vista y con la clase consultas_codigos.java

```
        public void LlamarCodigosBarra() {
        Integer valor_spinner = 0;
        
        String codigo = (String) view.jComboBox_modelos.getSelectedItem();
        valor_spinner = (Integer)view.jSpinner_cantidad.getValue();
        modelo.generarCodigosEnPDF(codigo, valor_spinner);
    } 
    
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if ( e.getSource() == view.jButton_descargar ) {
            LlamarCodigosBarra();
        }
    }
```

por ultimo muestro como se genera mi PDF

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

la libreria que uso es itext 5.11, si alguien sabe como hacer que no se sobreescriba el mismo archivo y sigan apareciendo mas se los agradeceria :(

[ACTUALIZACION]
clase completa consultas_codigo.java

```
package Models;

import com.itextpdf.text.BaseColor;
import com.itextpdf.text.Document;
import com.itextpdf.text.DocumentException;
import com.itextpdf.text.Element;
import com.itextpdf.text.Image;
import com.itextpdf.text.Paragraph;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.Barcode128;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfWriter;
import java.awt.Desktop;
import java.awt.HeadlessException;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Random;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;


public class consultas_codigos extends conexion {
        
        Random r = new Random();
        PdfWriter pdf;
    
    public ArrayList obtenerModelos(){
        ArrayList lista = new ArrayList();
        String query = "SELECT codigo_barras, modelo FROM inventario_general";
        
        try (Connection conn = getConnection();
            Statement st = conn.createStatement();
            ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery(query)) 
        {
            while(rs.next()){
            codigosBarras codigos = new codigosBarras(rs.getString("modelo"), rs.getString("codigo_barras"));
            lista.add(codigos);
            }
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            System.out.println("Error 3948:" + ex);
        }
        return lista;
    }
    
    public void generarCodigosEnPDF(String codigo, int cantidad){   
        Date date = new Date();
        DateFormat hourdateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("HH.mm.ss dd-MM-yyyy");
        String fecha = hourdateFormat.format(date);
        int codigo_aleatorio = 0;
        
        String query = "SELECT codigo_barras FROM inventario_general WHERE modelo = '"+codigo+"';";
        System.out.println(query);
        String resultado_codigo = "";
        
        try (Connection conn = getConnection();
            Statement st = conn.createStatement();
            ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery(query))
        {
            if (rs.next()) {
                resultado_codigo = rs.getString("codigo_barras");
            }
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            System.out.println("Error 351: " + ex + " No se pudo pana");
        }
        
        try {
            int i = 1;
            Document doc = new Document(); //paso 1: creamos el documento

            pdf = PdfWriter.getInstance(doc, new FileOutputStream("codigo_barras_"+fecha+".pdf")); //paso 2: instanciamos el doc y donde se creara
            doc.open(); //paso 3: abrimos el documento
            Barcode128 code128 = new Barcode128();
            
            while (i <= cantidad) {                
                codigo_aleatorio = (r.nextInt(10000)+1);
                code128.setCode(resultado_codigo);
                code128.setCodeType(Barcode128.CODE128);
                

                Image img = code128.createImageWithBarcode(pdf.getDirectContent(), BaseColor.BLACK, BaseColor.BLACK);
                img.scalePercent(220);
                img.setAlignment(Element.ALIGN_CENTER);
                
                Paragraph titulo = new Paragraph("Codigo de Fabricante: " + codigo_aleatorio, new com.itextpdf.text.Font(com.itextpdf.text.Font.FontFamily.COURIER, 12));
                titulo.setAlignment(Element.ALIGN_CENTER);
                float scaler = ((doc.getPageSize().getWidth() - doc.leftMargin() - doc.rightMargin() - 0 / img.getWidth()) * 60);
                
                
                doc.add(titulo); //añadimos el doc
                doc.add(img);
                doc.add(new Paragraph(" "));
            i++; //iterador
            
            }
            doc.close(); //cerramos el documento
            pdf.close();
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Codigos de Barra Generados Correctamente!");           
            
        } catch (DocumentException | HeadlessException | IOException ex) {
            System.out.println("Error 6164:" + ex);
        }      
    }
```

}

Comment: Esa consulta concatenando el input, _no bueno_, mala práctica.

Comment: analizemos esta linea `pdf = PdfWriter.getInstance(doc, new FileOutputStream("codigo_barras_"+fecha+".pdf"));` si la fecha siempre es igual sobrescribira el viejo documento debes usar otra forma de llamar al documento para hacerlo unico te recomiendo agregar la fecha dentro del metodo `generarCodigosEnPDF` para que se actualiza al llamarlo. ya que no se ve donde se inicializa la variable `fecha`

Comment: lo mando por parametros del metodo?

Comment: la variable fecha la tengo instanciada al inicio de la clase, de esta forma public class consultas_codigos extends conexion {
        
        Random r = new Random();
        PdfWriter pdf;
        Date date = new Date();
        DateFormat hourdateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("HH.mm.ss dd-MM-yyyy");
        String fecha = hourdateFormat.format(date);

Comment: @Fran el código adicional, EN la pregunta porfa. En los comentarios se va a perder.

Comment: donde lo añado?:c

Comment: ya lo agregue a la pregunta mi clase completa

Comment: Hermano le atinaste! si era eso, como te puedo dar la respuesta acertada!?

Comment: Solo se puede dar acertada a las respuestas no a los comentarios.

Comment: añade una respuesta y te la marco!:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solucionado, coloque los objetos de fecha y hora dentro del metodo, nose si sea una buena practica pero funciono!

```
 public void generarCodigosEnPDF(String codigo, int cantidad){   
    Date date = new Date();
    DateFormat hourdateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("HH.mm.ss dd-MM-yyyy");
    String fecha = hourdateFormat.format(date);
    int codigo_aleatorio = 0;
    
    String query = "SELECT codigo_barras FROM inventario_general WHERE modelo = '"+codigo+"';";
    System.out.println(query);
    String resultado_codigo = "";
    
    try (Connection conn = getConnection();
        Statement st = conn.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery(query))
    {
        if (rs.next()) {
            resultado_codigo = rs.getString("codigo_barras");
        }
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        System.out.println("Error 351: " + ex + " No se pudo pana");
    }
    
    try {
        int i = 1;
        Document doc = new Document(); //paso 1: creamos el documento

        pdf = PdfWriter.getInstance(doc, new FileOutputStream("codigo_barras_"+fecha+".pdf")); //paso 2: instanciamos el doc y donde se creara
        doc.open(); //paso 3: abrimos el documento
        Barcode128 code128 = new Barcode128();
        
        while (i <= cantidad) {                
            codigo_aleatorio = (r.nextInt(10000)+1);
            code128.setCode(resultado_codigo);
            code128.setCodeType(Barcode128.CODE128);
            

            Image img = code128.createImageWithBarcode(pdf.getDirectContent(), BaseColor.BLACK, BaseColor.BLACK);
            img.scalePercent(220);
            img.setAlignment(Element.ALIGN_CENTER);
            
            Paragraph titulo = new Paragraph("Codigo de Fabricante: " + codigo_aleatorio, new com.itextpdf.text.Font(com.itextpdf.text.Font.FontFamily.COURIER, 12));
            titulo.setAlignment(Element.ALIGN_CENTER);
            float scaler = ((doc.getPageSize().getWidth() - doc.leftMargin() - doc.rightMargin() - 0 / img.getWidth()) * 60);
            
            
            doc.add(titulo); //añadimos el doc
            doc.add(img);
            doc.add(new Paragraph(" "));
        i++; //iterador
        
        }
        doc.close(); //cerramos el documento
        pdf.close();
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Codigos de Barra Generados Correctamente!");           
        
    } catch (DocumentException | HeadlessException | IOException ex) {
        System.out.println("Error 6164:" + ex);
    }      
}
```

agradezco a [@alfabravo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/6798/alfabravo) porque encontro la respuesta :D

Comment: Si esa es la respuesta correcta, márcala para saber que tu pregunta ya tiene solución. 
Por cierto, no sé si en tu caso nunca habrá más de un PDF con el mismo código de barras, pero en caso de cada uno tener un codigo, podrías usar el código de barras como nombre en vez de la fecha (o las dos cosas). Básicamente se te sobreescribe por crear un pdf con el mismo nombre de uno existente, define el nombre que veas correcto para evitar repeticiones